# How to perform a single ScriptDb query to return multiple missing keys (logical OR)

Tags: google-apps-script

I can find objects in a ScriptDB that are invalid* only partially.

By way of example if all objects in the db should have both a `type` and an `id` i can query such that any that have *neither* by logical `AND`.

```
var DB = ScriptDb;

DB.getMyDb().query({
  type: DB.not( DB.anyValue() ),
  id: DB.not( DB.anyValue() )
});
```

But, what would be the best way, if any, of querying to find object with *either* missing by logical `OR`.

There is a `QueryOperator` for `OR` within values, but I can't see a single query route to find all invalid objects using keys.

I am currently passing one of the criteria as a search and then using a `while … hasNext()` loop to filter the rest. I'm trying to shave performance bottlenecks wherever I can and the `while … hasNext() … next()` pattern is one of them.

---

**invalid only by my example app's definition.*

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something similar to MongoDB [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) operator, but currently there is nothing like it in ScriptDB. You should open an enhancement in the [google-apps-script-issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), it would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

Mantain another boolean field then query in that field only. Every time the db object change you need to update that boolean too.

Comment: In the future that would be the case. In this instance I have a load of older data in a different form that needs clearing out. No matter I'll do two queries.